# Overheat VAIO VGN-AW31ZJ; 100°C everywhere

Tags: sony-vaio, overheating, throttling

Lately my laptop is always overheated and, to avoid shouting downs, it's always throttling. Any hint about how i can solve this issue?

It's out of warranty so i prefer to do it on my own at first.

Comment: Dose it have warranty?

Comment: no it haven't...

Comment: More information could help. Always overheating? Just surfing the web? Certain applications? How are you checking the temps? Have you done anything to try and fix? Google return anything useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I'd do is clean out the fans. If they are clogged with dust they will prevent the computer from adequately cooling itself.

Comment: Yes, but most of the case it's sealed. How it's supposed to be opened?

Comment: You should be able to take it apart by unscrewing the screws on the bottom of the casing. An easier and quicker way is to get a can of compressed air and use it to blow the dust out of the fans by pointing it at the air vents.